# Batch scripting manipulate text file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

So I have this code that reads a text file, finds the string and put it on another text file and it's working. But my problem is there's a multiple string TEST1 in the textfile but I only need to get at least 1 line of TEST1. Thank you in advance I'm really stuck on this one.

```
@echo off
findstr /l "TEST1" *.txt > TEST1samp.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Found!
) else (
echo No matches found
)

@echo off
findstr /l "TEST2" *.txt > TEST2samp.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Found!
) else (
echo No matches found
)

@echo off
findstr /l "TEST3" *.txt > TEST3samp.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Found!
) else (
echo No matches found
)
```

Comment: It is not clear what result you are trying to achieve. Do you actually need TEST1sampl.txt at all? Or do you simply need to know if the search string is found somewhere in the file?

Comment: The phrase (idiom) _at least 1_ means _1 or more_. So how many lines do you get from `findstr` in case of _there's a multiple string TEST1 in the textfile_? And how many lines should be? An example: let the string TEST1 is 3× in file `f3.txt` and 1× in a file `f1.txt` and is not at all in a file `f0.txt`. What output expected in `TEST1samp.txt`?

Comment: For example if I run this script for error.txt to findstr test1, the result is there's a multiple line which contains test1. What I need to do is to get atleast 1 line in txtfile and transfer it on another textfile.

Comment: Again: The phrase (idiom) *at least 1* means *1 or more* and _multiple_ means _several or many_. That's the same, so you get what you want :)

Comment: I didn't get it JosefZ, sorry im really new on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language difficulty is that you saye you want `at least 1 line of TEST1` which means that you want 1 or more lines, but you also complain `there's a multiple string TEST1 in the textfile` and that is what your code would produce - more than one line.

If you want exactly one line, then it is clearer to say "I want just one line containing the target string to be written to the result file" - otherwise, we have an endless series of revisions to resolve the grey area.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "reportfilename=newfile.txt"
SET targetstring=28180521

DEL "%reportfilename%" >NUL 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /l "%targetstring%" *.bat') DO >"%reportfilename%" ECHO %%a&GOTO done
:done
IF EXIST "%reportfilename%" (ECHO %targetstring% found) ELSE (ECHO %targetstring% NOT found)

:: change targetstring without having it explicitly in the batchfile & try again

SET /a targetstring +=1
DEL "%reportfilename%" >NUL 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /l "%targetstring%" *.bat') DO >"%reportfilename%" ECHO %%a&GOTO done2
:done2
IF EXIST "%reportfilename%" (ECHO %targetstring% found) ELSE (ECHO %targetstring% NOT found)

GOTO :eof
```

This procedure tests for the string "28180521" and then the string "28180522" in the `*.bat` files, producing different results because the first will exist in the first case, but not in the second. It will however contain exactly one line if it exists.